# Why do I get a Null Reference Exception assigning delegate methods to the event handler Button.OnClick?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, delegates, event-handling

This question is different from the marked duplicate as it does not go into detail about this specific example of delegates.

I would like to neatly add a delegate method to my button on click events. This is done using C# in Xamarin. When running the app in my emulator I am getting the below unhandled exception.

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Below is the code I am using

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

namespace AudioTour
{
    [Activity(Label = "AudioTour", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            // Find Buttons
            Button startButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.startAudio);
            Button stopButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.stopAudio);
            // Set Screen
            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
            // Assign Delegate Methods to Buttons
            startButton.Click += StartAudio;
            stopButton.Click += StopAudio;  
        }
        // Start Audio Method
        void StartAudio(object sender, EventArgs ea)
        {
            // Do Code
            Console.WriteLine("Starting Audio");
        }
        // Stop Audio Method
        void StopAudio(object sender, EventArgs ea)
        {
            // Do Code
            Console.WriteLine("Stopping Audio");
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: In which line of code do you get the NullReferenceException?

Comment: StartButton.Click

Comment: If you debug it, are `startButton` and `stopButton` filled correctly? Looks like one of them is null. Or on which line did you receive this error?

Comment: Then the function `FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.startAudio);
` returns null

Comment: please do SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main); statement before find button.

Comment: Thank you all. You helped me work out that it was not actually the delegate that was undefined but infact the button was null.